# How to structure relative imports in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I've found myself in an import error situation I thought I was well past. I'm running Python 3.7.4 in VSCode on Windows 10. Without any further ado.. this is my folder and file structure, starting with folder crypto_code:

/crypto_code:

```
__init__.py (blank)

/crypto_driver:
    __init__.py (blank)
    crypto_balances.py

/crypto_exchg:
    __init__.py (blank)
    exchg_lens.py
    bittrex_lens.py
    coinbase_lens.py
```

Top of file coinbase_lens.py:

```
import exchg_lens
```

Top of file crypto_balances.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
from crypto_exchg import coinbase_lens
```

Running coinbase_lens as main imports exchg_lens without error.

Running crypto_balances.py seems to recognize the paths/structure, but throws 'ModuleNotFoundError': No module named 'exchg_lens'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue I've found troublesome as well. I have a setup that works and avoid messing with it. However this is good practice (for me) so ...

As a starting position I suggest abandoning `import sys` and `sys.path.append`. These are hacks that obscure the issue. If you use a linter (flake8 is what I use) then it will complain about `sys.path.append` appearing before `imports` and it is worth respecting what the linter dislikes.

I think the starting issue is, are you writing a module or a program. Restructuring your folders to provide a clear distinction.

```
/
program.py
/crypto
    __init__.py (empty)
    /driver
        __init__.py (empty)
        crypto_balances.py
    /exchg
        __init__.py (empty)
        coinbase_lens.py
        exchg_lens.py
    /test
        __init__.py (empty)
        test_coinbase_lens.py
```

program.py

```
from crypto.driver import crypto_balances
from crypto.exchg import coinbase_lens, exchg_lens
```

crypto_balances.py

```
from ..exchg import coinbase_lens
print('crypto_balances')
```

coinbase_lens.py

```
from . import exchg_lens
print('coinbase_lens')
```

exchg_lens.py

```
print('exchg_lens')
```

When run from the / folder produces

```
python .\program.py
exchg_lens
coinbase_lens
crypto_balances
```

Of course you should have a test framework to run tests on your module. The test file has the following content. Pytest sucessfully finds (and runs) the following test.

```
from crypto.exchg import coinbase_lens

def test():
    assert True
```

Later ... you can look at the package `__init__.py` and adding the imports and `__all__` there to allow namespace management. Easy enough to add later.

### Edited to add

Feels like I am missing a useful point that is worth including. `\crypto\__init__.py` and `program.py` can be altered to allow you to manage how the namespace of the module appears to the program.

`__init__.py` becomes

```
from crypto.driver import crypto_balances
from crypto.exchg import coinbase_lens, exchg_lens
__all__ = [
    "crypto_balances",
    "coinbase_lens", "exchg_lens"
]
```

program.py is now ...

```
from crypto import crypto_balances
from crypto import coinbase_lens, exchg_lens
```

Comment: @standard glad it helped. I added a piece that I personally find quite useful.

Comment: It did help.. but I'm struggling with how to work within /driver/crypto_balances.py without import errors on /exchg/coinbase_lens.py. I now get 'attempted relative import beyond top-level package'.

Comment: @standard It's a different way of working. I have a couple of approaches. 1) debug within a pytest test, 2) have a program at top level that vscode is set to always run when I debug 3) have many top level programs that I manually run in debug. For 3) I often forget and run the module directly. ... It's a hassle :( but the code is cleaner as a result.